# What are these red triangle-shaped things?

Tags: terraria

[image: Triangle shaped shiny red things]

I found this red triangle formation while exploring and I am unsure what it is.  I don't want to touch it until I know; what is it?

Comment: For Adventure, you could have tried interacting with them. Then you'd have gotten an answer pretty quickly =) (+1 anyway, though)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those are [Rubies](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ruby). In addition to appearing in stone, gems can be found attached to the sides of other blocks, particularly in a [Gemstone Cave](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gems). You can harvest them with your pickaxe directly, or by breaking all the blocks next to them.

Comment: You can use them in many items, see http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ruby

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the selected answer, User.

Comment: whoops ok i marked it

Answer (score -5):

those are rubies that you can collect with any pickaxe you can make a ruby staff that does 21 magic damage ; you can improve your mana by collecting falling stars that fall from the sky at night and you can make mana crystals

Comment: This was already answered 3 years ago... and I don't know how the falling stars relates?